# Magento Admin Menu Acl

Tags: magento, menu, acl

The code add a new menu in backend. But i have a permission denied problem on the new page. I add the controller and helper.

My adminhtml.xml

```
    <config>
<menu>
    <mycustomtab module="colorswitch" translate="title">
        <title>My Custom Tab</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
            <index module="colorswitch" translate="title">
                <title>Index Action</title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/colorswitch</action>
            </index>
            <list module="colorswitch" translate="title">
                <title>List Action</title>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/custom/list</action>
            </list>
        </children>
    </mycustomtab>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <custom translate="title" module="colorswitch">
                    <title>My Controller</title>
                    <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <index translate="title">
                            <title>Index Action</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        </index>
                        <list translate="title">
                            <title>List Action</title>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        </list>
                    </children>
                </custom>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

I havent no idea, where is the problem.

Comment: pls check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In menu you hve used node

```
 <config>
  <menu>
    <mycustomtab module="colorswitch" translate="title">
```

and below

```
   <acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <**custom** translate="title" module="colorswitch">
```

Change this custom node to mycustomtab

Answer (score 0):

Your code :

```
<acl>
    <resources>
    <admin>
        <children>
            <custom translate="title" module="colorswitch">
                <title>My Controller</title>
                <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <index translate="title">
                        <title>Index Action</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    </index>
                    <list translate="title">
                        <title>List Action</title>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    </list>
                </children>
            </custom>
        </children>
    </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Should Be :

```
<acl>
    <resources>
    <admin>
        <children>
            <mycustomtab translate="title" module="colorswitch">
                <title>My Controller</title>
                <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <index translate="title">
                        <title>Index Action</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    </index>
                    <list translate="title">
                        <title>List Action</title>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    </list>
                </children>
            </mycustomtab>
        </children>
    </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```